# PyCharm - RuntimeError: Cannot sign bundle (macOS Big Sur)

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, setup.py, dmg

I have finished my code, and then I tried to convert it to `.dmg`. I'm using Mac with macOS Big Sur. I have used this tutorial to see how I can convert the code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIAlkQEw8Gc.

I have installed `py2app` as it's shown in video and PyCharm's Terminal gives me this

`Successfully installed altgraph-0.17 macholib-1.14 modulegraph-0.18 py2app-0.24`

after that I have modified `setup.py` file by adding this code

```
from setuptools import setup

APP=['main.py']
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

Then I typed in terminal `python setup.py py2app` and received a

`RuntimeError: Cannot sign bundle '/Users/aleks/PycharmProjects/CollegeApp_Final/dist/main.app'`

I have looked a bit on what terminal printed and found this error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
/Users/aleks/PycharmProjects/CollegeApp_Final/dist/main.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

which repeats a lot of times.

How can I solve this problem or is there other ways to convert my code?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when I have seen this it is because some library file has a bad format.  In my case, I see the file

Contents/Frameworks/liblzma.5.dylib
invalid or unsupported format for signature

I run in a virtual environment and have HomeBrew installed;  My fix is to copy the one from Homebrew into the virtual environment

For example,

With the virutal environment installed at

```
PROJECT_VENV=~/PycharmProjects/PyUt/pyenv-3.10.6
```

copying this file fixes the same problem

```
sudo cp /opt/homebrew/opt/xz/lib/liblzma.5.dylib ${PROJECT_VENV}/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs
```